# Azure image vision API User-Agent name?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, user-agent, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying tagging service. I have some image hotlink protection in my .htaccess file which blocks access to image. I would like to allow access to images for vision service and I added this in my .htaccess files:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !azure [NC]

But, I guessed wrong, "azure" is not name of User-Agent.

Can you help me, please tell me how to allow this service to access image, by user agent, IP address or domain name?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is working, just to allow blank referer, like this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$